# Make an HTML input field appear as just the text in the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML form with a number of `input` fields that are added dynamically with content in each field using jQuery.

Is it possible to hide the fact that these fields are input fields and only display them as the content in the field?

I don't want to hide the entire field *and* it's contents --- just hide the fact that its an input type field.

I've tried jQuery's `hide()` and `$('#foo').css('display','none')`, but that hides the entire field.

The idea is that there could be a large number of fields, but I don't want the user to see all the input text fields.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the borders to show?

Comment: If you do not want them to look like input's why make them input's?

Comment: You want to display the text but not the field?  Why use an input field?  Or do you want to just reformat the input field css to look different?

Comment: If I understand you right, you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xVFX2/ But remember, that this could confuse your users

Comment: I need to be able to submit the contents of the inputs when the form's submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this :

```
$('.dynamic input').each(function() {
    $('<div/>').html($(this).val()).insertAfter($(this).hide());
});
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this this, so I marked this as the answer.  I captured the value of the field and am just styling it as needed using CSS and then hiding the input with hide().  Works for my purpose without having to re-style the input field itself necessarily.

Answer (score 13):

Start with something like this:

```
input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Remove the background as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css `border:none;` property and make sure the box is long/tall enough.

Comment: Though this is not a responsive solution, But this really works !! Kudos